# How to make an array of multiple nested objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have such an object.

```
let Filus = {
     male: {
    hat: [1],
    jacket: [2],
    pants: [3],
    shoes: [4],
    suit: [5]
  }
};
```

I want to get this array from this object.

```
let Filus = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

How to do it?

Comment: What is the key of the nested object?

Comment: @JackBashford why is retagged with `ecmascript-6`? Because it has `let`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Object.values` and `flat` - this works even if you don't know the key of the nested object:

```js
let Filus = {
  male: {
    hat: [1],
    jacket: [2],
    pants: [3],
    shoes: [4],
    suit: [5]
  }
};

const res = Object.values(Object.values(Filus)[0]).flat();
console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var Filus = {
  male: {
    hat: [1],
    jacket: [2],
    pants: [3],
    shoes: [4],
    suit: [5]
  }
};

var res = Object.keys(Filus[Object.keys(Filus)[0]]).map(function(key) { 
  return Filus[Object.keys(Filus)[0]][key];
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  return acc.concat(curr);
});

console.log(res);
```

---

It's also easy if you have the key:

```js
let Filus = {
  male: {
    hat: [1],
    jacket: [2],
    pants: [3],
    shoes: [4],
    suit: [5]
  }
};

const res = Object.values(Filus.male).flat();
console.log(res);
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var Filus = {
  male: {
    hat: [1],
    jacket: [2],
    pants: [3],
    shoes: [4],
    suit: [5]
  }
};

var res = Object.keys(Filus.male).map(function(key) { 
  return Filus.male[key];
}).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  return acc.concat(curr);
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get values of nested object `male` using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and then use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let Filus = { male : { hat: [1], jacket: [2], pants: [3], shoes: [4], suit: [5] } };

const res = Object.values(Filus.male).flat();
console.log(res)
```

You can also do that without `flat()` using `concat()` and spread operator.

```js
let Filus = { male : { hat: [1], jacket: [2], pants: [3], shoes: [4], suit: [5] } };

const res = [].concat(...Object.values(Filus.male));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and return all found values of the object and it's nested objects.

This approach relies on language inherent order of objects.

```js
function* values(o) {
    if (o && typeof o === 'object') for (let v of Object.values(o)) yield* values(v);
    else yield o;
} 

let filus = { male: { hat: [1], jacket: [2], pants: [3], shoes: [4], suit: [5] } },
    result = [...values(filus)];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object is from a JSON string, the numbers can be extracted during parsing :

```js
var arr = [], json = '{"male":{"hat":[1],"jacket":[2],"pants":[3],"shoes":[4],"suit":[5]}}'

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.toFixed && arr.push(v))

console.log(arr)
```